# REGEXP_EXTRACT() Error when creating a dimension

Tags: looker-studio

So...

I use data studio for a news publisher website. I was trying to extract a date which is available in almost every page title we have.

I'd like to use it as a dimension in my Data Studio tables.

I tried it a couple of ways. All of them returned errors.

First, I simply tried to extract the date from the page title.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title, '(..\/..\/....)')
```

Then, I thought I might be getting errors because not all of the page titles contain a date. Only the ones related to articles (the homepage and indexes, for example, don't have it).

So, I tried this:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page Title, '(..\/..\/....)') THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title, '(..\/..\/....)') ELSE 'None' END
```

I tried both ways with the parentheses and without them. With the quotation marks and without them.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, when using CASE within Data Studio you can only return static text, not tie the result to a function. In other words, Data Studio will only parse something like this: CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page Title, '(../../....)') THEN 'Yay!' ELSE 'None' END

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea why a simple `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title, '(..\/..\/....)')` wouldn't work?

Comment: One way to overcome the limitations of Google Data Studio is to import the data into Google Sheets instead (there are connectors available for that). You have a lot more possibilities there. Then you can use the sheet as a data source for Data Studio.